# Is there a way to set an Application Shortcut in the Keyboard Preference Pane via Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, settings, sudo

I'd like to have a bootstrap for my custom keyboard shortcuts to use on multiple machines...

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `defaults` command on `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist`.

The file's structor seems a bit overly complex, but:*

> 131072: Shift
>    262144: Control
>    524288: Option
>    1048576: Command
>
> Add modifier values together in the 3rd parameter to combine them.
>
> { AppleSymbolicHotKeys = {
>
> # Move focus to the menu bar - Control, F2
>    7 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 120, 262144 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Move focus to the Dock - Control, F3
>    8 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 99, 262144 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Move focus to active or next window - Control, F4
>    9 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 118, 262144 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Move focus to window toolbar - Control, F5
>    10 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 96, 262144 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Move focus to floating window - Control, F6
>    11 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 97, 262144 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # ??? - Control, F1
>    12 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 122, 262144 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Change the way Tab moves focus - Control, F7
>    13 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 98, 262144 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Turn zoom on or off - Command, Option, 8
>    15 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 56, 28, 1572864 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Zoom in - Command, Option, =
>    17 = { enabled = 0; value = { parameters = ( 61, 24, 1572864 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Zoom out - Command, Option, -
>    19 = { enabled = 0; value = { parameters = ( 45, 27, 1572864 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Reverse Black and White - Command, Control, Option, 8
>    21 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 56, 28, 1835008 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Turn image smoothing on or off - Command, Option, \
>    23 = { enabled = 0; value = { parameters = ( 92, 42, 1572864 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Increase Contrast - Command, Control, Option, .
>    25 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 46, 47, 1835008 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Decrease Contrast - Command, Control, Option, ','
>    26 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 44, 43, 1835008 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Move focus to the next window in application - Command, backtic
>    27 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 96, 50, 1048576 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Save picture of screen as file - Command, Shift, 3
>    28 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 51, 20, 1179648 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Copy picture of screen to clipboard - Command, Control, Shift, 3
>    29 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 51, 20, 1441792 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Save picture of selected area as file - Command, Shift, 4
>    30 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 52, 21, 1179648 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Copy picture of selected area to clipboard - Command, Control, Shift, 4
>    31 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 52, 21, 1441792 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # All Windows - F9
>    32 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 101, 0 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Application Windows - F10
>    33 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 109, 0 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # All Windows (Slow) - F9
>    34 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 101, 131072 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Application Windows (Slow) - F10
>    35 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 109, 131072 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Desktop - F11
>    36 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 103, 0 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Desktop (Slow) - F11
>    37 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 103, 131072 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # ??? - Command, Option, T
>    50 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 116, 17, 1572864 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Move focus to the window drawer - Command, Option, quote
>    51 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 39, 50, 1572864 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Turn Dock Hiding On/Off - Command, Option, D
>    52 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 100, 2, 1572864 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # ??? - F14
>    53 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 107, 0 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # ??? - F15
>    54 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 113, 0 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # ??? - Option, F14
>    55 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 107, 524288 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # ??? - Option, F15
>    56 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 113, 524288 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Move focus to the status menus - Control, F8
>    57 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 100, 262144 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Turn VoiceOver on / off - Command, F5
>    59 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 96, 1048576 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Select the previous input source - Command, Option, Space
>    60 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 32, 49, 1572864 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Select the next source in the Input Menu - Command, Option, Shift, Space
>    61 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 32, 49, 1703936 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Dashboard - F12
>    62 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 111, 0 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Dashboard (Slow) - F12
>    63 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 111, 131072 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Show Spotlight search field - Command, Shift, Space
>    64 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 49, 1179648 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Show Spotlight window - Control, Shift, Space
>    65 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 49, 393216 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Dictionary MouseOver - Command, Shift, E
>    70 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 101, 2, 1179648 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Hide and show Front Row - Command, Esc
>    73 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 53, 1048576 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Activate Spaces - F8
>    75 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 100, 0 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Activate Spaces (Slow) - Shift, F8
>    76 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 100, 131072 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Spaces Left - Control, Left
>    79 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 123, 262144 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Spaces Right - Control, Right
>    81 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 124, 262144 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Spaces Down - Control, Down
>    83 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 125, 262144 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Spaces Up - Control, Up
>    85 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 126, 262144 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Show Help Menu - Command, Shift, /
>    91 = { enabled = 0; };
>    92 = { enabled = 0; };
>    98 = { enabled = 0; value = { parameters = ( 47, 44, 1179648 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Switch to Space 1 - Control, 1
>    118 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 18, 262144 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Switch to Space 2 - Control, 2
>    119 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 19, 262144 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Switch to Space 3 - Control, 3
>    120 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 20, 262144 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> # Switch to Space 4 - Control, 4
>    121 = { enabled = 1; value = { parameters = ( 65535, 21, 262144 ); type = standard; }; };
>
> 122 = { enabled = 0; };
>    123 = { enabled = 0; };
>    124 = { enabled = 0; };
>    125 = { enabled = 0; };
>    126 = { enabled = 0; };
>    127 = { enabled = 0; };
>    128 = { enabled = 0; };
>    129 = { enabled = 0; };
>    130 = { enabled = 0; };
>    131 = { enabled = 0; };
>    132 = { enabled = 0; };
>    133 = { enabled = 0; };
>    134 = { enabled = 0; };
>    135 = { enabled = 0; };
>    136 = { enabled = 0; };
>    137 = { enabled = 0; };
>    138 = { enabled = 0; };
>    139 = { enabled = 0; };
>    140 = { enabled = 0; };
>    141 = { enabled = 0; };
>    142 = { enabled = 0; };
>    143 = { enabled = 0; };
>    144 = { enabled = 0; };
>    145 = { enabled = 0; };
>    146 = { enabled = 0; };
>    147 = { enabled = 0; };
>    148 = { enabled = 0; };
>    149 = { enabled = 0; };
>    }; }

Two decent sources:

- http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=114785
- http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/defaults-symbolichotkeys/

*this is a bit dated

Answer (score 0):

The shortcuts for all applications are stored in ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist, and application-specific shortcuts are stored in `~/Library/{,Containers/*/Data/Library/}Preferences/*.plist`.

```
defaults write -g NSUserKeyEquivalents '{
"Show in Finder" = "$@r";
"Reveal" = "$@r";
"Minimize" = "\0";
"Minimize All" = "\0";
}'

defaults write com.apple.Safari NSUserKeyEquivalents '{
"Reopen Last Closed Window" = "~@r";
"Reopen All Windows from Last Session" = "~$@r";
"Mail Contents of This Page" = "\0";
}'
```

The shortcut format is described in http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/site/cocoa-text.html. If a menu item was assigned to nil, pressing L would trigger it in some applications like Audacity.